# AWS Data Migration Service, MongoDB as source datapoint

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, data-migration

I am trying to access AWS DMS for mongoDB as a source datapoint but unable to access.
It displays the following error:
 **Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=1020414, errMessage=Failed to create new client connection Endpoint initialization failed., errDetails= A user name must be specified when the authentication 'Type' is set to 'Password'. Endpoint initialization failed.]**

I have selected authentication mode as NONE since we don't have users for our database. I am trying with MongoDB atlas for Source endpoint and also amazon instance through DMS.

I am new to DMS..Please help.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: namrata-sahay did you find a solution to this problem? I am facing the same problem.